# Passing a variable between two test cases?

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a simple set of test cases in which I first assign a variable to a figure. Then in another test case, I am trying to access that variable and log in out.

Here's what I have so far.

```
TestCase1
    ${FIGURE}=  get text  xpath=//*[@id="reportTableId"]/tr[1]/td[14]
    set variable  ${FIGURE}
    log  ${FIGURE}

TestCase2
    log  ${FIGURE}
```

However, in the second test case. `${FIGURE}` is showing as unassigned.

Is there a step that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables in test cases are local scope and not visible in other tests. If you want to access `${FIGURE}` in another test, you should set it as suite variable:

```
TestCase1
    ${FIGURE}=  get text  xpath=//*[@id="reportTableId"]/tr[1]/td[14]
    set suite variable  ${FIGURE}
    log  ${FIGURE}

TestCase2
    log  ${FIGURE}
```

Comment: Thanks! I also neglected to list the variable in the section at the top of my script. Added it and it worked :) Thanks!